# If one SMTP Server is down, routing all requests to another, how to achieve?

Tags: routing, smtp, email-server

I have an application which uses e-mail notifications at many levels, so if an SMTP Server is down, I get in trouble. I can't switch the SMTP adress in all my configs fast, or lets say even don't want that.

So does anyone know how to "reroute" all requests from one smtp to another? is this a big deal ? thanks

Comment: There are some Options, you can build a Cluster, 2nd MX Entry or simple reroute traffic to another host. What Option is interesting for you?

Comment: reroute traffic seems to be the easiest solution. thanks

Comment: A load balancer or HA controller would also allow servers to be out of commission and remain completely transparent to the client side.

Comment: Can you explain your Infrastructure? How the Server connected together?

Comment: local area network they are all in the same data center.

Comment: Does your application support DNS MX records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it, and yes it is a (relatively) big deal to set up, though not a huge deal if you're already using automation tools like Puppet or Chef.

Ideally, your setup would be the following for true high availability:

```
SMTP 1 (192.168.1.21) <-----> Load Balancer 1 (192.168.1.10)
                       \   /           |
                         +             |-------------- VIP (192.168.1.100)
                        / \            |
SMTP 2 (192.168.1.22) <-----> Load Balancer 2 (192.168.1.11)
```

- You have HAproxy running on **both** load balancers, which listens to port 25 on the VIP, and forwards traffic to port 25 on **both** SMTP servers.
- Keepalived controls the VIP and will fail-over from **Load Balancer 1** to **Load Balancer 2**.
- In the event of an SMTP server failing, it will be removed from the pool and requests will be diverted to the remaining healthy server.
- In the event of a load balancer failing, if the failed LB is the secondary, there won't be any change. If the failed LB is the primary, the VIP will fail-over to the secondary.
- This setup can cope with failure of **one** LB and **one** SMTP server at once, but **both** SMTP/LBs cannot fail.

Comment: I've recently tried to implement this, and came up with the fact that load balancing SMTP isn't so simple. You either have to enforce the use of authenticated SMTP (try switching 10,000 clients' configuration to this new configuration sometime), or have a load balancer that only allows certain IP ranges to send e-mail, or you'll have an open proxy server. Unfortunately, I haven't found a load balancer that does the latter yet.